# Perl - SSHProcessError The ssh process was terminated error

Tags: perl, perlnetssh

I have built a script which will do `ssh` to the remote server and execute certain command. To make execution successful I was waiting until I get `END` keyword from the command result.

So in positive test case scenario this works fine.

```
...

foreach my $ip( @list_of_ips ){
    chomp($ip);
    eval {
        $ssh = SSH_Connection( $ip, $user, $passwd );
        print "Connection is Success to $ip\n" if($ssh);
    };

    $command_to_execute = "<forming a command which needs be execute in remote server>";
    print "$command_to_execute\n";

    my $str = 'END';

    eval{
        $ssh->send("$command_to_execute; echo $str");
    };
    $ssh->waitfor($str, undef);
    last if($ssh);
}
...
...

sub SSH_Connection {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new ( host => $host, user => $user, password => $passwd, raw_pty => 1, no_terminal => 0 );

    my $login_output;
    my $handledie = eval {
        $login_output = $ssh->login();
    };

    if ( $@ ) {
        if ($@ =~ m/SSHConnectionError/i ) {
            print  "SSH Connection Error\n";
            next;
        } elsif ( $@ =~ m/SSHProcessError/ix ) {
            print "SSH Process Error\n";
            next;
        } elsif ( $@ =~ m/SSHConnectionAborted/ix ) {
            print "SSH Connection Aborted\n";
            next;
        } else {
            print "SSH Unknown Error: $@\n";
            next;
        }
    }
    if ($login_output !~ /Last login/) {
        die "Login has failed.";
    } else {
        return $ssh;
    }
    print "SSH to ip failed\n";
}
```

But when connection to remote host is successful and command execution fails, the following error shows up and exits from the script.

```
SSHProcessError The ssh process was terminated at ...script.pl line 47
```

We have `$ssh->waitfor($str, undef);` at line 47.

How can we resolve this issue? TIA.

Comment: Does putting the `waitfor()` inside an `eval` block to catch the exception help?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, sometimes commands failed to execute. thats why I have added the `eval` block.

Comment: But the `waitfor()` is not inside the `eval` in your code example

Comment: What do you mean by *"command execution fails"* ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I agree that `waitfor()` should be inside `eval`. Now its not throwing an error. So basically `$ssh->waitfor($str, undef);` will wait for the string `END` from command output. If it doesn't finds it, then wait forever. So wait forever have any time limit?